# How Test Database (PostgreSQL) with Loadrunner

Tags: database, load-testing

I want to test a Database(PostgreSQL) with Loadrunner, I want to know if there is any sample code for that.

Answer (score 1):

ODBC, if you have a postgresql ODBC driver and your client is an odbc client you can record the connection.  Or, you can put your queries through an open ODBC client and record them

Or, see VUGEN guide, Advanced Concepts, Building virtual users in Visual Studio.   This may help as well, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-interfaces.html